# MySQL relationships in CodeIgniter php

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, relationship

I have 2 tables with relationships that I want to be able to connect via PHP. I'm using code igniter. Is there a way to write "Select [column] from BrandID where [Inventory ID] = [BrandID ID]" using the code igniter active record?

```
private function getData(&$tbl_name) {
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->get($tbl_name);
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function Inventory() {
    $tbl_name = 'new_inventory';
    return $this->getData($tbl_name);
}
```

I believe a join will help with this.

Comment: Can you show the code of the current function in your model?

Comment: theres a little bit more but i cut out the irrelevant details (IE a search functionality)

Comment: For best results you should provide a minimally reproducible example. Two functions may seem like all you need, but without your development context it looks like two, possibly related, functions which handle generic data and really don't have anything wrong with them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
public function getData(){

  $this->load->database();

  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('Inventory');
  $this->db->join('BrandID', 'Inventory.id = BrandID.id');

  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();

}
```

Comment: worked like a charm. thank you! not sure why you're getting downvotes though